# "A Currency is Required if a Value Exists in a Money Field" - Default Currency Is Set

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm having a serious issue with one of my managed solutions, I have a custom workflow which creates a bunch of custom entities and these custom entites have several money fields on them.

Here's what happens when I run my workflow:

1. Custom workflow goes into 'waiting' state and throwns a null reference exception.
2. Several entities have been created, but one of them has null vlaues in the money fields (they default onLoad to £0.00).
3. When I open this record, I get the error message mentioned in the tite of this post.

A few things you should know:

1. The default currency is set in the system (to Pound Sterling).
2. I have tried to following JavaScript in the OnLoad() event of my form as has been suggested elsewhere on the web:

---

```
var lookupData = new Array(); 
var lookupItem= new Object(); 
lookupItem.id = "{7bCA916E76-FA28-E211-8C7C-0800273EE9D1}"; 
lookupItem.entityType = "transactioncurrency"; 
lookupItem.name = "Pound Sterling";     
lookupData[0] = lookupItem; 
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("transactioncurrencyid").setValue(lookupData);
```

---

If this JS is on thje form and I attempt to create a new record I get the error:

> Error: 'Xrm.Page.getAttribute(..)' is null or not an object

Can anyone advise as to what it is I have to do here?

This error only occurs on the live system, not in the development environment.

Comment: Do you know the ids are different between environments? I dont think you should have to set the currency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the ID of the currency you are trying to set is different in the live environment than in the dev environment.

You need to get the ID of the "Pound Sterling" currency from the Live environment and put it where "insert here":

```
lookupItem.id = "--insert here--"; 
lookupItem.entityType = "transactioncurrency"; 
lookupItem.name = "Pound Sterling";
```

Then it will work.